# Can't play wav file from Javascript in Firefox for Mac

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox, audio, embed

I have the following html file that plays a wav file when the user hovers over the 'Play' anchor tag.  It works perfectly on IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari on both Windows and Mac - except for Firefox on the Mac which does not play the file.

We know the file type is supported because if the autostart attribute of the embed tag is set to true then the wav file plays as expected in Firefox for Mac, but the mouseover of the anchor tag fails to play the file.

Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
function PlayAudio() {
    var s = document.getElementById("soundFile");
    s.Play();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <embed src="MySound.wav" enablejavascript="true" type="audio/wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="soundFile" />
    <a href="#" onmouseover="PlayAudio()">Play</a>     
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

Still no success after 3 weeks. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: wav? are you sure it's a good idea?
That's one heavy file to download.
Consider converting it into mp3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by using javascript to create **embed** when want to play and remove it to stop. And the **embed** has autostart="true".

```
function Play() {
    // Create and append <embed> element.
}

function Stop() {
    // Remove <embed> element.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the file type is not supported. Try using an MP3 format, which will also be smaller, which is a bonus (typically about one tenth of the size of a WAV file).

Comment: We know the file type is supported because if autostart is set to true the wav file plays correctly when the page loads.

Comment: I have also tried using an mp3 file instead of a wav file and I get exactly the same problem - works on all bowsers except Firefox on Mac only.

Anyone?